# How to store unlimited array of 10 numbers mapped to address?

Tags: solidity, arrays

Really new to Solidity,

Trying to create a simple Keno game, I want to store an array of 10 numbers for each ticket and map it to the address, each address can have an unlimited number of tickets.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "hardhat/console.sol";


contract Keno {

   address public manager;

   uint public minimumBet;

// Create a ticket struct to represent a single ticket
   struct Ticket { 
       bytes32[] numbers;
   }

   mapping(address => Ticket) public numbers; 

}
```

'Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state variables'

Just trying to get my head around it and getting a bit stuck. Reading through the Solidity docs too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the error message is quite clear:

> Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state variables

In your case, the problem is that you're using recursive types for the `numbers` public state variable.
So, to resolve this, either make numbers into a different structure layout that doesn't involve recursive types. Or, just simply re-define `numbers` as either `private` or `internal`, depending on your requirements, as in:

```
mapping(address => Ticket) private numbers;
```

or

```
mapping(address => Ticket) internal numbers;
```

Though, you will also need to define getter functions to be able to publicly access the data inside your `numbers` state variable. You can learn more about state variable visibility and getter functions [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).